# Returning new store in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm adding redux to an existing app, and I have trouble updating the state of a component which is subscribed to the store. Minimal chunk with my setup:

DivsContainer.js

```
const DivsContainer = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    collections : PropTypes.array.isRequired
  },

  render() {
      return (
          <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            {this.props.collections.map((coll,  i) => (
              <div
                key={coll.id}
                name={coll.name}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
      )
  }

})

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      collections: state.collectionsReducer.collections,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        onClick: () => {
            dispatch(addCollection())
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DivsContainer)
```

Reducers.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {ADD_COLLECTION, REMOVE_COLLECTION} from './actions'

const initialState = {
    collections: [
         {
             id: 1,
             name: "mock",
         }  
     }
    ]
}

function collectionsReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_COLLECTION:
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: action.id,
                    name: action.name,
                }
            ]
        default:
            return initialState
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({collectionsReducer})

export default rootReducer
```

actions.js

```
export const ADD_COLLECTION = 'ADD_COLLECTION'

let nextCollectionId = 2

export function addCollection() {
    return {
        type: ADD_COLLECTION,
        id: nextCollectionId++,
        name: 'mock',
    }
}
```

The reducer is called, so I suspect the problem occurs when returning the new state object (reducers is incorrect) because I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined  render
>   @DivsContainer.js:

Answer (score 2):

Your reducer is kind of messed up. `collectionsReducer` returns an array but your `initialState` is an object with an array in it.

The reducer probably should be:

```
return {
    ...state,
    collections: [...state.collections, {id: action.id, name: action.name}],
};
```

and your `mapStateToProps` should be:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        collections: state.collections,
    };
}
```

because you're mapping `state` to `props` and your state has the shape of `{collections: []}` not `{collectionsReducer: collections: []}`

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your reducer, ADD_COLLECTION is returning an array [something], it is not {collections: something}. So the reducer does not have collections any more, and it complains 'map' of undefined . You need to return {collections: [something]} in your ADD_COLLECTION